# Aligning and Resizing Divs In HTML

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm attempting to align DIVs like below:

[image: what I want]

Without having to calculate the exact amount of pixels that makes it fit.

Here is my code currently,

```
<div style="border:solid;height:50%;width:50%;background-color:green;">

<div style="float:left;width:50%;height:50%;background-color:red;"></div>

<div style="float:left;width:25%;height:25%;background-color:blue;"></div>

</div>
```

which gives the output below:

[image: What I currently have]

I've looked around and cannot find a solution that works, when I come to resize or change browser,

Any links or answers would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Had to give outer `div` a static `px` height and width.
And the inner `div` are responsive with `%`.

And even as lamp5 posted, vh is a better option.
Resizes according to your window size.

```html
<div style="border:solid;height:100vh;width:100%;background-color:green;">
  <div style="position:relative; height:50%">
    <div style="position:absolute;width:50%;float:left;height:100%;background-color:red;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;width:25%;float:left;height:50%;background-color:blue;bottom:0px;margin-left:50%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I noticed that this answer depends on the heights being a specific px value, other wise they won't line up. I'm looking for a answer where it can be resized.

Comment: Your outer `div` is having a value already. And when you give it `height:50%`, it's in reference to the outer `div`. Post your entire HTML file in codepen and show us please. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/)

Comment: I've already posted my code above, I'm going to apply theory to my actual project.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my solution.

```css
.green{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background: green;
}

.red{
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
background: red;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
}

.blue{
width: 25%;
height: 25%;
background: blue;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">
<div class="red">
</div><div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've noticed in the .green height its value is 100vh; what does the "vh" do?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vh+in+css&oq=vh+in+css&aqs=chrome..69i57.3024j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: vw, vh, vmax i vmin are Viewport Units and 100vh = your screen height, you have to definied absolute height of container 100vh or 500px when you want to use relative height: 50% inside.

Answer (score 0):

There are more modern and safer methods than floats .

One of : 
You could make set to your child boxes next rules

```
vertical-align: bottom;
display: inline-block;
```

Another one of my favourite is a variation with flex 
you only need to set to your parent div next rules

display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;

But it will align your child divs to bottom of your parrent div , as a variant you can set padding-bottom to your parent div to achive result you whant

Comment: Have you got any examples which I could view?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your divs responsive, you can use flexbox.
First, modify a little bit your html to improve readability

```
<div class="yourDiv" id="greenDiv">
     <div id="support"><!--support div -->
      <div class="yourDiv" id="redDiv"></div> 
      <div class="yourDiv" id="blueDiv"></div>
     </div> <!--end support -->
   </div><!--end greenDiv-->
```

Here I'm using the bigger green div as container for the other two divs and a support div within it. For styling rules use separeted CSS stylesheet

```
 .yourDiv{
   /*the common properties for all divs */
   border:solid;
   height:50%;
   width:50%;   
  }

 #greenDiv{
   background-color:green;
   display:flex;
   justify-content:flex-start;
   flex-direction:row;
   flex-wrap:nowrap;
 }

 #support{ 
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  aligh-items:flex-start;
  width:75%;
  height:inherit;
 }

 #redDiv{
   display:inline;
   background-color:blue;}

 #blueDiv{
   display:inline;
   background-color:blue;
   align-self:flex-end;
   width:25%;
   height:25%;
 }
```